# Parallel.ForEach starts to idle with Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a problem with the `Parallel.ForEach` loop. It works as it should as long I don't `Invoke` a method to increase the `ProgressBar.Value` of the parent GUI program.
Where `KeinPapierVersand` is a simple `List<int>` object and `EinzelnachweisDruckDatum` is a `DateTime`.

```
Parallel.ForEach(KeinPapierVersand, partner =>
{
    generate_PCL_nachweis(partner, EinzelnachweisDruckDatum, true, false);
    generate_BGF_Report(partner, EinzelnachweisDruckDatum, false);
    
    //If the following line is uncommented, the loop starts to idle after about 200 
    // processed Items and will never reach the code after the loop.

    myProgressbar_einzelnachweis_druck.Parent.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
    { 
        myProgressbar_einzelnachweis_druck.Value = 
                                         myProgressbar_einzelnachweis_druck.Value + 1; 
    }));
});
```

These are my first steps with parallelism in C#. I have no clue what's the problem here, there is no exception thrown (had it in a try/catch before).
Without the `Invoke` of the `ProgressBar` the loop ends always without a problem.

Why is my logic not working? Where is my error in reasoning? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you're calling the `Parallel.ForEach` method from your main UI thread. Like, in response to a button click or other UI event. Assuming this is the case, then `Parallel.ForEach` line itself is running on the main UI thread and will block that main thread waiting till all the concurrent work that it's requesting is done.

The way that `Invoke()` works is that it sends a message to the main UI thread and waits for the message to get processed. When that processing is complete, it will return and progress will continue. In your code, when a thread calls `Invoke()`, it's going to wait there for `Invoke` to complete. However, `Invoke` never will complete because the main thread is blocked by the `Parallel.ForEach` and can't process the request to update the progress bar till the `Parallel.ForEach` is complete. It's a type of deadlock.

There are lots of ways to fix this problem. They all essentially amount to getting the `Parallel.ForEach` off the main thread. One of the most simple ways to do this, if you can here (don't have enough of a code sample to tell) is to use async/await to kick off a task that then calls the `Parallel.ForEach` and awaits the results. This will free up your main thread to be able to process the progress bar updates.

Once you get that working, you may also want to consider switching to using `BeginInvoke` here instead of `Invoke` because `BeginInvoke` doesn't wait for the main thread to process the message before completing. It's a bit trickier to use because the update order isn't guaranteed and the update could even occur after the `ForEach` completes. It won't fix your root problem, you have to fix that first, but it'll be more efficient because the `Invoke()` version will actually slow down your `Parallel` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and very clear explanation. So it is a classic dead-lock situation. I will try out some ways and then update my answer accordingly.